# Using reduce with initial value in a Pipe with toolz Python

Tags: python, pipe, reduce, toolz

I am looking to perform a reduce operation as part of a pipe to sort dict items based on a key.
e.g.

```
from toolz import pipe

items = [{"id":1, "val":1}, {"id":2, "val":2}, {"id":2, "val":3}]
res = pipe(items, reduce(combine_items), other_ops...)
# res = {1: [{'id': 1, 'val': 1}], 2: [{'id': 2, 'val': 2}, {'id': 2, 'val': 3}]}

def combine_items(record_list, item):
    record_list.setdefault(item.get("id"), []).append(item)
    return record_list
```

I've managed to do this using a lambda i.e.

```
res = pipe(items, lambda x: reduce(combine_items, x, {}), other_ops...)
```

My question is whether there is another way I can do this without having to use a lambda within the pipe?

The main issue I have is that I need a default value for my list append to work properly within the reduce and I am unsure if there is a way to fill this correctly within the pipe otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than rolling your own `combine_items`, you can use [`groupby()`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.groupby) from toolz which does exactly what you're trying to do here:

```
from toolz import groupby

res = groupby('id', items)
```

If you want to use that as part of a pipe, then you can use [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to pass `groupby()` a key argument:

```
from toolz import groupby, pipe
from functools import partial

res = pipe(items, partial(groupby, 'id'), other_ops...)
```

Comment: I would go a step further - import curried toolz functions (`from toolz.curried import groupby, pipe`) and then you can write just `res = pipe(items, groupby('id'), other_ops...)`